# Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

while trying to fetch the data by using Query and exposing as API getting exception

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, 
String> {

@Query(value="Select * from Employee",nativeQuery = true)
 @RestResource(path = "byEmp", rel = "byEmp")
 List<Map> findTest();

 }
```

URL: http://localhost:8080/employeeEntities/search/byEmp

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.lambda$getRequiredPersistentEntity$2(PersistentEntities.java:78) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.getRequiredPersistentEntity(PersistentEntities.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.13.RELEASE.jar:2.0.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.wrap(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:72) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.13.RELEASE.jar:3.0.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toResource(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:55) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.13.RELEASE.jar:3.0.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.entitiesToResources(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:110) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.13.RELEASE.jar:3.0.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.toResources(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:80) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.13.RELEASE.jar:3.0.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.lambda$toResource$1(RepositorySearchController.java:209) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.13.RELEASE.jar:3.0.13.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_181].at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.toResource.
```

If i tried to call from any other class by creating method i am able to fetch records

Answer (score -1):

List<**Employee**> findTest();